# converting a decimal/hex value in a register to ascii

Tags: string, assembly, ascii

So say I have this value in a register ebx: 30303420

I want to convert that and print out  the corresponding ascii values. So it SHOULD print out

004

```
30  == 0
30  == 0
34  == 4
20  == space character.
```

How would I get that to print on the screen?

This is 80x86 architecture, using assembly code.

Comment: depends on the operating system and the method you want to use, you can make bios calls or calls to library functions to whatever library you want to link this code with, or program the video card directly, etc, etc.  This doesnt have much to do with assembly language though.

Comment: i don't think you understand what I'm trying to do :/

Comment: You're not explaining what you want to do. You'll need to specify your environment.

Comment: In assembly code, what would I need to convert a decimal in a register to an ascii character

Comment: Well, you do not have a "decimal" in your register, you already have it as ascii, so you don't have to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question have a couple unclear details.

1- If you have 30303420 Hex value in ebx, then you have 4 Ascii characters, precisely "004 ", that is:

```
mov ebx,30303420H       ;is exactly the same than:
mov ebx,"004 "
```

You have NOT any decimal value (wich one?), so there is not any conversion here.

2- If you want to show that ebx value in the screen, so it shows "004 ", then you must specify under which operating system your program will run in order to use the appropiate services. For example, if you want to use old-style MS-DOS INT 21H functions, that also run in a DOS Window in Windows, then this segment do that:

```
mov     cx,4        ;counter = 4 characters
    ;
next:
rol     ebx,8       ;rotate left EBX 1 byte: place next char in BL
mov     dl,bl       ;DL = char to show
mov     ah,2        ;AH = VIDEO OUTPUT function
int     21H         ;DOS kernel service Int: show the char
loop    next        ;repeat 4 times
```

However, if your program run under Linux, the method to show ebx value is entirely different. Also, your program may use a C library function in a different way, or be a Windows-compliant program, or use BIOS INT 10H service (in charge of the screen), or even directly access the video circuitry, etc, etc, etc...

Comment: Where did you found that `rol` instruction rotates with `BL`?

Comment: @flyer: Perhaps in any [x86 CPU architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561502(v=vs.85).aspx) reference manual? `bl: Low 8 bits of ebx`

Comment: I see now. Somehow mixed this with `shld` instruction. +1.